# Plot a simple conversion funnel in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple dataframe that looks like this:

```
df
   steps  numbers     rate
 1 clicks 332835  100.000000
 2 signup  157697  47.379933
 3  cart   29866   8.973215
 4  buys   17012   5.111241
```

How can I plot a simple conversion funnel instead of a barchart?

Comment: What does that mean? Do you have an example of what you want the final plot to look like?

Comment: You can check the image on this link: (http://www.programering.com/a/MDM1ATMwATA.html). I'm looking to plot something like this

Comment: @anonymous You should include the example in the question.

Comment: I actually found out this link: http://www.r-bloggers.com/sales-funnel-visualization-with-r/  for sales funnel visualization in R but it I was hoping if there was a simpler way to plot

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you must do the funnel thing, it's just a variation on bar chart:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2) # for melt()

# get data
dat <- read.table(text=
"steps  numbers     rate
clicks 332835  100.000000
signup  157697  47.379933
cart   29866   8.973215
buys   17012   5.111241", 
header = T)

# add spacing, melt, sort
total <- subset(dat, rate==100)$numbers
dat$padding <- (total - dat$numbers) / 2
molten <- melt(dat[, -3], id.var='steps')
molten <- molten[order(molten$variable, decreasing = T), ]
molten$steps <- factor(molten$steps, levels = rev(dat$steps))

ggplot(molten, aes(x=steps)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = value, fill = variable),
           stat='identity', position='stack') +
  geom_text(data=dat, 
            aes(y=total/2, label= paste(round(rate), '%')),
            color='white') +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('grey40', NA) ) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  labs(x='stage', y='volume')
```

[image]

That said, **there's no real point in a "funnel chart"** - the same information can be presented in a plain bar chart with less fuss:

```
# get data
dat <- read.table(text=
"steps  numbers     rate
clicks 332835  100.000000
signup  157697  47.379933
cart   29866   8.973215
buys   17012   5.111241", 
header = T)

# order x axis
dat$steps <- factor(dat$steps, levels = dat$steps)

# plot
ggplot(dat, aes(x=steps, y=numbers)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(rate), '%')), vjust=-0.5
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Helped me a lot! I just do not understand this line below, can you explain it to me?
`melt(dat[, -3], id.var='steps')`

Comment: `dat[, -3]` : `dat`, after dropping the 3rd column. `melt(x, id.var='steps')`: convert `x` from wide to long format, using the column `steps` as the id variable. `?reshape2::melt` for more info

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do a simple funnel in highcharts.  My dataframe looks like this:

```
# data is a df called check_stage
check_stage

# A tibble: 9 × 4
  stage_name               count x     percent
  <ord>                    <int> <chr>   <dbl>
1 Opportunity Disqualified   805 1        13.5
2 Qualifying                5138 2        86.5
3 Evaluation                1773 3        29.8
4 Meeting Scheduled         4104 4        69.1
5 Quoted                    4976 5        83.7
6 Order Submitted           1673 6        28.2
7 Closed Won                1413 7        23.8
8 Closed Lost                957 8        16.1
9 Nurture                   1222 9        20.6

library(highcharter)

# make a funnel plot of stage
options(highcharter.theme = hc_theme_smpl(tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 1,
                                                         pointFormat = "{point.y}%")))


hc <- check_stage %>%
  hchart(
    "funnel", hcaes(x = stage_name, y = percent), name = "Proportion of Leads")

hc
```

[image]