# How to fix ggplot2 code for sales funnel?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to run the code mentioned [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sales-funnel-visualization-with-r/):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# creating a data samples
# content
df.content <- data.frame(content = c('main', 'ad landing',
'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', 'product 4',
'shopping cart',
'thank you page'),
step = c('awareness', 'awareness',
'interest', 'interest', 'interest', 'interest',
'desire',
'action'),
number = c(150000, 80000,
80000, 40000, 35000, 25000,
130000,
120000))
# customers
df.customers <- data.frame(content = c('new', 'engaged', 'loyal'),
step = c('new', 'engaged', 'loyal'),
number = c(25000, 40000, 55000))
# combining two data sets
df.all <- rbind(df.content, df.customers)

# calculating dummies, max and min values of X for plotting
df.all <- df.all %>%
group_by(step) %>%
mutate(totnum = sum(number)) %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(dum = (max(totnum) - totnum)/2,
maxx = totnum + dum,
minx = dum)

# data frame for plotting funnel lines
df.lines <- df.all %>%
select(step, maxx, minx) %>%
group_by(step) %>%
unique()

# data frame with dummies
df.dum <- df.all %>%
select(step, dum) %>%
unique() %>%
mutate(content = 'dummy',
number = dum) %>%
select(content, step, number)

# data frame with rates
conv <- df.all$totnum[df.all$step == 'action']

df.rates <- df.all %>%
select(step, totnum) %>%
group_by(step) %>%
unique() %>%
ungroup() %>%
mutate(prevnum = lag(totnum),
rate = ifelse(step == 'new' | step == 'engaged' | step == 'loyal',
round(totnum / conv, 3),
round(totnum / prevnum, 3))) %>%
select(step, rate)
df.rates <- na.omit(df.rates)

# creting final data frame
df.all <- df.all %>%
select(content, step, number)

df.all <- rbind(df.all, df.dum)

df.all <- df.all %>%
group_by(step) %>%
arrange(desc(content)) %>%
ungroup()

# calculating position of labels
df.all <- df.all %>%
group_by(step) %>%
mutate(pos = cumsum(number) - 0.5*number)

# defining order of steps
df.all$step <- factor(df.all$step, levels = c('loyal', 'engaged', 'new', 'action', 'desire', 'interest', 'awareness'))
list <- c(unique(as.character(df.all$content)))
df.all$content <- factor(df.all$content, levels = c('dummy', c(list)))

# creating custom palette with 'white' color for dummies
cols <- c("#ffffff", "#fec44f", "#fc9272", "#a1d99b", "#fee0d2", "#2ca25f",
"#8856a7", "#43a2ca", "#fdbb84", "#e34a33",
"#a6bddb", "#dd1c77", "#ffeda0", "#756bb1")

# plotting chart
ggplot() +
theme_minimal() +
coord_flip() +
scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
geom_bar(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), stat="identity", width=1) +
geom_text(data=df.all[df.all$content!='dummy', ],
aes(x=step, y=pos, label=paste0(content, '-', number/1000, 'K')),
size=4, color='white', fontface="bold") +
geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=max(maxx), ymin=maxx, group=1), fill='white') +
geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=maxx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=minx, ymin=min(minx), group=1), fill='white') +
geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=minx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
geom_text(data=df.rates, aes(x=step, y=(df.lines$minx[-1]), label=paste0(rate*100, '%')), hjust=1.2,
color='darkblue', fontface="bold") +
theme(legend.position='none', axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),
axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Because I got a duplicated factor error:

```
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
  duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
```

and this ugly plot as a result
[image]

I changed this piece of code:

```
df.all$content <- factor(df.all$content, levels = c('dummy', c(list)))
```

into:

```
df.all$content <- factor(df.all$content, levels = c(list)))
```

As a result I get this plot:[image]

According to the writer of the blog, this should be the result instead:

[image]

I think I don't have to explain that my plots are not what they should be. I haven't been able to figure out yet what causes the problem. Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this is a lot of code to create a bad graphic which is hard to read and difficult to understand. It attempts very hard to resemble the proverbial "sales funnel" thereby concealing essential information. BTW, the result looks more like a goblet than a funnel.

Comment: I am trying to understand how the width of the bars relate to either the K value labels or the percentages.  Anyway, looks like the associations are broken.  Check the levels of each of your factors, are they in the right order?  You should set the levels of each based on the levels of the determining variable.

Comment: @R.S. The percentages are a particular bad flaw in the design of this graphic. The first three values are the share of total counts vs. the previous step. The last three values are the shares of the counts in step _action_. _new_, _engaged_, and _loyal_ sum up to 100% or 120K absolute. So, the displayed percentages have different meanings and should never have been shown in one curve. The basic problem here is that two different measures, the sales funnel and customer loyality, are mixed up to get a "fancy" looking graph.

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35854964/plot-a-simple-conversion-funnel-in-ggplot

Comment: Please make the title of your question informative so future readers with a similar problem could find it to. In other words, SO is meant to help all programmers in the world with similar issues, rather being a personal assistant to specific users.

Comment: @DavidArenburg What title would you suggest?

Comment: The one that describes your exact problem the best. In other words, what would you search for if you had this same problem. I'm sure it wouldn't be just "*How to fix ggplot2?*".

Comment: @UweBlock agreed. It took me a minute of staring to realize that is what's going on, and that I shouldn't understand the line graph of percentages to be a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of some updates in packages. The working code is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

# creating a data samples
# content
df.content <- data.frame(content = c('main', 'ad landing',
                                  'product 1', 'product 2', 'product 3', 'product 4',
                                  'shopping cart',
                                  'thank you page'),
                         step = c('awareness', 'awareness',
                                   'interest', 'interest', 'interest', 'interest',
                                   'desire',
                                   'action'),
                         number = c(150000, 80000,
                                    80000, 40000, 35000, 25000,
                                    130000,
                                    120000))
# customers
df.customers <- data.frame(content = c('new', 'engaged', 'loyal'),
                           step = c('new', 'engaged', 'loyal'),
                           number = c(25000, 40000, 55000))
# combining two data sets
df.all <- rbind(df.content, df.customers)

# calculating dummies, max and min values of X for plotting
df.all <- df.all %>%
    group_by(step) %>%
    mutate(totnum = sum(number)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(dum = (max(totnum) - totnum)/2,
           maxx = totnum + dum,
           minx = dum)

# data frame for plotting funnel lines
df.lines <- df.all %>%
    distinct(step, maxx, minx)

# data frame with dummies
df.dum <- df.all %>%
    distinct(step, dum) %>%
    mutate(content = 'dummy',
           number = dum) %>%
    select(content, step, number)

# data frame with rates
conv <- df.all$totnum[df.all$step == 'action']

df.rates <- df.all %>%
    distinct(step, totnum) %>%
    mutate(prevnum = lag(totnum),
           rate = ifelse(step == 'new' | step == 'engaged' | step == 'loyal',
                         round(totnum / conv, 3),
                         round(totnum / prevnum, 3))) %>%
    select(step, rate)
df.rates <- na.omit(df.rates)

# creting final data frame
df.all <- df.all %>%
    select(content, step, number)

df.all <- rbind(df.all, df.dum)

# defining order of steps
df.all$step <- factor(df.all$step, levels = c('loyal', 'engaged', 'new', 'action', 'desire', 'interest', 'awareness'))
df.all <- df.all %>%
        arrange(desc(step))
list1 <- df.all %>% distinct(content) %>%
        filter(content != 'dummy')
df.all$content <- factor(df.all$content, levels = c(as.character(list1$content), 'dummy'))

# calculating position of labels
df.all <- df.all %>%
        arrange(step, desc(content)) %>%
        group_by(step) %>%
        mutate(pos = cumsum(number) - 0.5*number) %>%
        ungroup()

# creating custom palette with 'white' color for dummies
cols <- c("#fec44f", "#fc9272", "#a1d99b", "#fee0d2",
          "#2ca25f", "#8856a7", "#43a2ca", "#fdbb84",
          "#e34a33", "#a6bddb", "#dd1c77", "#ffffff")

# plotting chart
ggplot() +
    theme_minimal() +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
    geom_bar(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), stat="identity", width=1) +
    geom_text(data=df.all[df.all$content!='dummy', ],
              aes(x=step, y=pos, label=paste0(content, '-', number/1000, 'K')),
              size=4, color='white', fontface="bold") +
    geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=max(maxx), ymin=maxx, group=1), fill='white') +
    geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=maxx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
    geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=minx, ymin=min(minx), group=1), fill='white') +
    geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=minx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
    geom_text(data=df.rates, aes(x=step, y=(df.lines$minx[-1]), label=paste0(rate*100, '%')), hjust=1.2,
              color='darkblue', fontface="bold") +
    theme(legend.position='none', axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), 
          axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the order of the group in each bar is ..well, out of order.

Probably something changed with `ggplot` ordering factor, anyway reversing the solve the issue:

```
ggplot() +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
  geom_bar(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), position = position_stack(reverse = T), width=1, stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(data=df.all[df.all$content!='dummy', ],
            aes(x=step, y=pos, label=paste0(content, '-', number/1000, 'K')),
            size=4, color='white', fontface="bold") +
  geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=max(maxx), ymin=maxx, group=1), fill='white') +
  geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=maxx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
  geom_ribbon(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, ymax=minx, ymin=min(minx), group=1), fill='white') +
  geom_line(data=df.lines, aes(x=step, y=minx, group=1), color='darkred', size=4) +
  geom_text(data=df.rates, aes(x=step, y=(df.lines$minx[-1]), label=paste0(rate*100, '%')), hjust=1.2,
            color='darkblue', fontface="bold") +
  theme(legend.position='none', axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Where the intersting bit is:

```
geom_bar(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), position = position_stack(reverse = T), width=1, stat = 'identity')
```

Note that this should be update to use `geom_col`:

```
geom_col(data=df.all, aes(x=step, y=number, fill=content), position = position_stack(reverse = T), width=1)
```

As @Uwe Block said, this remains a ugly and hard to read. Something that would be somewhat better would be a Sankey diagram.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I replaced my ggplot code with yours, but your code doesn't seem to work neither. Are you sure you got the expected graph?

Comment: @GGamba +1 esp for the Sankey diagram you proposed as alternative