# Add percent change on a coord flipped `geom_bar()` chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

Some data:

```
sub_funnel_data <- structure(list(funnelstep = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Sessions", 
"Engaged Sessions", "Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email", 
"Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details", "Direct to Paid"
), class = "factor"), N = c(92853L, 33107L, 3469L, 3149L, 113L
), Drop = c(NA, 0.356552830818606, 0.104781466155194, 0.907754396079562, 
0.0358844077484916), Rate = c(1, 0.356552830818606, 0.0373601283749583, 
0.0339138207704651, 0.00121697737283663)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like:

```
sub_funnel_data
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  funnelstep                                           N    Drop    Rate
* <fct>                                            <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Sessions                                         92853 NA      1      
2 Engaged Sessions                                 33107  0.357  0.357  
3 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email      3469  0.105  0.0374 
4 Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details  3149  0.908  0.0339 
5 Direct to Paid                                     113  0.0359 0.00122
```

I can create a plot:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(funnelstep, desc(funnelstep)), N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#39cccc') +
  coord_flip()
```

Looks like:
[image]

I would like to add the drop in percentage on each step to this chart. [Similar to a question I posted a few years back.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824998/adding-percent-change-between-bars-on-a-ggplot)

I tried to modify the solution there to my needs but failed. I like the outcome of that solution, the only real difference is that now my plot is flipped.

Here's what I tried:

```
sub_funnel_data <- sub_funnel_data %>% mutate(End = lag(N),
                                               xpos = 1:n() - 0.5,
                                               Diff = End - N,
                                               Percent=paste(round(Diff / End * 100, 1), "%"))
```

Then my attempted plot:
Before `coord_flip()`:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(funnelstep, desc(funnelstep)), N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#39cccc') +
  stat_summary(aes(label = scales::comma(..y..)), fun = 'sum', 
               geom = 'text', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xpos, y = End, xend = xpos, yend = N)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = xpos, y = End - Diff / 2, label = Percent), hjust = -0.2)
```

[image]

I can already see this is flawed. But I want to use it with `coord_flip()` anyway:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(reorder(funnelstep, desc(funnelstep)), N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#39cccc') +
  stat_summary(aes(label = scales::comma(..y..)), fun = 'sum', 
               geom = 'text', col = 'white', vjust = 1.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=xpos, y = End, xend = xpos, yend = N)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = xpos, y = End - Diff / 2, label = Percent), hjust = -0.2) +
  coord_flip()
```

Looks like:
[image]

How can I add percentage drop off on each step to my chart? Ideally I'd like to use the `Rate` field in `sub_funnel_data` to display the corresponding percentage drop between each step. I like the lines and %ages shown at the midpoint on each chart in the linked post, I just cannot replicate it to my current use case.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017460/position-geom-text-on-dodged-barplot) help

Comment: I tried adding `position = position_dodge(width = 1)` within geom_text per that solution but the plot looks a mess. I wonder if it's because I have a factor variable, funnel step. I tried changing `geom_text(aes(x = xpos, ...` to `geom_text(aes(x = reorder(xpos, desc(funnelstep)),` but similar messy result :/

Comment: is this because of your labels.  Can you try to wrap those labels with `str_wrap`

Comment: i.e. `sub_funnel_data %>% mutate(funnelstep = str_wrap(funnelstep, width = 10)) %>%ggplot`

Comment: I see a `NA %` in the Percent column

Comment: str_wrap did make the plot look slightly better before coord_flip(). BUt the plots still fundamentally off. Yes, the first item in Rate will be NA since it divides each row based on the lag of numeric column N. I.e. it's supposed to show the % that move from ecah step starting from Sessions, through Engaged Sessions... all the way to the end point Direct to Paid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reorder your `aes()` variables (in this case using `rev()`) and make some tweaks it looks ok, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

sub_funnel_data <- structure(list(funnelstep = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Sessions", 
                                                                         "Engaged Sessions", "Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Enter Email", 
                                                                         "Subscription Funnel - Arrives on Payment Details", "Direct to Paid"), 
                                                         class = "factor"), N = c(92853L, 33107L, 3469L, 3149L, 113L),
                                  Drop = c(NA, 0.356552830818606, 0.104781466155194, 0.907754396079562, 
                                           0.0358844077484916), Rate = c(1, 0.356552830818606, 0.0373601283749583, 
                                                                         0.0339138207704651, 0.00121697737283663)),
                             row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

sub_funnel_data %>% mutate(End = lag(N),
                           xpos = 1:n() + 0.5,
                           Diff = End - N,
                           Percent=paste(round(Diff / End * 100, 1), "%")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(funnelstep, desc(funnelstep)), y = N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#39cccc') +
  stat_summary(aes(label = scales::comma(..y..)),
               fun = "sum", geom = "text",
               col = "grey25", vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = rev(xpos), y = End, xend = rev(xpos), yend = N)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = rev(xpos - 0.1), y = End - Diff / 1.5, label = Percent), hjust = -0.2) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: example_1.png]

This is an alternative including the 'Rate' variable:

```
sub_funnel_data %>% mutate(End = lag(N),
                           xpos = 1:n() + 0.5,
                           Diff = End - N,
                           Percent = paste("\u2190 ", round(Diff / End * 100, 1), "% drop", sep = ""),
                           Rate = paste("(", round(Rate * 100, 1), "%", " of total Sessions)", sep = "")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(funnelstep, desc(funnelstep)), y = N)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = '#39cccc') +
  stat_summary(aes(label = paste("n = ", scales::comma(..y..), sep = "")),
               fun = "sum", geom = "text",
               col = "black", vjust = 0,
               hjust = -0.05, size = 4) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = rev(xpos), y = End, xend = rev(xpos), yend = N * 1.1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = rev(xpos - 0.1), y = End - Diff / 1, label = Percent), hjust = -0.2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = rev(xpos - 0.7), y = End - Diff, label = Rate), color = "black", hjust = 0) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: example_2.png]

Do either of these solve your problem?

Comment: This is truly great, sincere thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome - I learned a lot trying to solve your problem - thanks for providing all the required details in your question :)